# Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated - How to fix this?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
Update upd_tbl a1
set last_update_date=sysdate(), 
rno=(select rno from sid b1
     where a1.rowid_object=b1.rowid_object
    )
where rowid_object in (select rowid_object from sid);
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting this error - SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated.

Kindly guide how to fix this error in Snowflake.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this below query works correctly:                                                                  
 Update upd_tbl a1
set last_update_date=sysdate(), 
rno=rno from sid b1
     where a1.rowid_object=b1.rowid_object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, however, it should be noted that if you have a many-1 relationship between the rowid_object join condition, this may need to be revisited using exists logic for a boolean test:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-subquery.html

The following code reflects the pattern used for updating a table based on another table's data:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/update.html

```
Update
    upd_tbl a1
set
    a1.last_update_date = sysdate(),
    a1.rno = b1.rno
from sid b1
where a1.rowid_object = b1.rowid_object;
```

Comment: Is there any added value or scenario for using alias at  `SET alias.col =  alias2.col2` and not just `SET col=alias2.col`? The target table for update is fixed and defined at `UPDATE upd_tbl a1`. It seems to be superfluous.

Comment: It's purely for readability, and habit when working with multiple tables that share the same attribute names.

Comment: I tried the same already and it worked successfully. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SherinShaziya apologies!  I missed your comment above, yes you had the same answer.  You likely posted as an answer, and it didn't meet the character count threshold and was converted to a comment.